# Spring Boot + JPA + Hibernate Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

excuse me for my terrible English.
I have project, it's written on Spring Boot + Hibernate + JPA. I have this entity relations:

client class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Client {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ClientWallet> wallets;

}
```

Wallet class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallets")
public class ClientWallet {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "wallet")
    private List<ClientTransaction> transactions;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;
}
```

Transaction class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class ClientTransaction {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id", nullable = false)
    private ClientWallet wallet;
}
```

And i have @Repository for each entity (extends CrudRepository) Like this:

```
@Repository
public interface WalletsRepository extends CrudRepository<ClientWallet, Long> {
    ClientWallet findByAnotherField(String anotherFiels);
}
```

Also, i have background thread, this thread receiving Wallet object by one of his fields, adding new Transaction object and saving object. All new data physycally appears in database, but don't visible in my html page before re-authorization or restarting application.

How fix it? Need use 1 session for all threads? How do it?

And second question. Why fetsh=LAZY thow LazyInitializationException? I added @Transactional annotation for my service class but nothing changed.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add html source, related ui code and exception stacktrace for lazy exception

Comment: ERROR Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: myapp.client.Client.wallets, could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: myapp.client.Client.wallets, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: In HTML code nothing important. I tryed print values from web controller - same result. It's not a HTML cache, if u about it.